# Pyramid i18n and HTML5

Tags: python, html, internationalization, pyramid, chameleon

Does Pyramid i18n of .pt files support HTML5 mark-up? Currently the i18n tag extractor (Babel?) seems to want XHTML based input and does not accept HTML5 mark-up. Thus if you want to use i18n in .pt files you are forced to write them in XML'ish way?

Comment: HTML5 is just as much XML as earlier versions of HTML: it can be written both in XML and non-XHTML form.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'Chameleon 2.0 did not seem to work with Babel' ? No Chameleon version uses Babel, so your remark feels off.

Comment: Hi Wichert! Thanks for coming back as nice question as this. By following this tutorial https://pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/narr/i18n.html I tried to extract msgids from .pt files. If .pt file is not valid XML (e.g. self-closing tags and stuff) parser fails (I assume this is Babel parser, not Chameleon itself) because it only accepts XML'ish HTML as input.

Comment: Also clarified the question - hopefully better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chameleon 1 included two Babel extraction plugins (one for python code and one for XML files), which is what the Pyramid documentation is referring to. Chameleon 2 no longer includes those plugins and focuses on its core functionality of being a template library. These two plugins have been cleaned up and are now included in the new  [lingua package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lingua). The pyramid documentation has been updated to reflect that since Pyramid 1.1 (as you can see [in the Pyramid 1.1 i18n chapter](https://pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.1/narr/i18n.html)).

The lingua XML plugin uses [expat](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pyexpat.html) to parse its input, so will indeed fail on HTML files that do not use XML notation. Since I personally feel quite strongly that XML notation is a much better choice I am not likely to chance the lingua implementation to support non-XML syntax. There is one exception: lingua does allow for missing namespace declaration.

Comment: What would it take to have HTML5 compatible parser to plugged in? Do we talk about adding just one plug-in file or is more pervasive change? html5lib supports DOM output http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/

Comment: It would take adding an alternative for https://github.com/wichert/lingua/blob/master/src/lingua/extractors/xml.py .

Comment: For what it's worth: lingua no longer requires templates to be valid XML, and can process HTML 5 templates without problems.